# Defining default jQuery tab based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define the search type they want. A tab is selected as the default by using `$('#type_search').click();` however this causes a problem when refreshing a results page. If a different search type is selected and then the page is refreshed, the default tab is automatically selected so it doesn't return the correct results even though the page URL says it is correct.

My question is, how can I define the default tab from the section in the URL if a query is active and if there is no active query use the default tab? I hope you can understand what I'm saying.

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    $('#type_search').click();
    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#' + type + '/') == 0) {
        query = window.location.hash.replace('#' + type + '/', '').replace('/', '');
        $('#query').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
    var textlength = $('#query').val().length;
    if (textlength <= 0) {
        $('#query').focus();
    } else {
        $('#query').blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you think the accepted answer is incorrect, just unaccept it.  No need to flag for a moderator on your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I had that problem too. It's pretty simple. On page ready you just take the anchor from the URL and simulate a click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  url = document.location.href.split('#');
  $('#'+url[1]).click();
});
```

Comment: Wherever you put the rest of your jQuery. I would put it at the endmost but don't think that matters much. I just tested it, works fine for me.