# Firing a jQuery search after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define which search type they want to use. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #**type**/***query***/. However, when you either reload the page, click a result which goes to a different page or return back from a previous page the search results are no longer there. My question is, how can I fire the jQuery search again when the page is reloaded?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    $('#type_search').click();
    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search Script';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    var textlength = $('#query').val().length;
    if (textlength <= 0) {
        $('#query').focus();
    } else {
        $('#query').blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: on domready, check the presence of a hash on the url. if its there, run the search

Comment: Same way as answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717466/defining-default-jquery-tab-based-on-url/6717507#6717507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do, is do the same thing u do when the query button is clicked, at page load:

```
$(function () {
   if (window.location.hash != "") {
      // run the search function here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the hash code should stay in window.location.hash, why don't you just read out the hash again? Here is a little tutorial: [Get URL parameters & values with jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)